Counting and adding sum in a table as a new column
Prometheus matric is my_matric and
I have this table with 3 columns Type, Id & Status -
| TYPE| ID | Status |
| ----| ---|--------|
| ABC | 123| 1      |
| XYZ | 456| 0      |
| ABC | 456| 1      |
| PQR | 123| 1      |
| ABC | 456| 0      |
| XYZ | 123| 1      |
| XYZ | 123| 0      |
| PQR | 123| 0      |
| ABC | 123| 1      |
And would like to print this in grafana display through PromQL-



TYPE
ID
Total
Status0
Status1




ABC
123
4
1
3


XYZ
456
3
2
1


PQR
123
2
1
1



I tried lable_join etc but at the end not getting the table in above format.
What should query be for that?
Thanks.
Tried combination of various QLs
sum by (Status_type) (label_replace (my_matric, "Status_type", "$1", "Status", "0"))
sum (increase(Type[10h])) by (my_matric)
but nothing seems giving the desired results

What's your PromQL query and are you trying to sum numbers stored in labels ?
